# Find / Replace Text Using Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have chunks of text that I need to remove, or simply replace with "".

Below is an excerpt of the text

1. `$prep->bindValue(':PYOtherExpensesAmt',$summaryData['*PYOtherExpensesAmt*'])?$row['PYOtherExpensesAmt']:''));`
2. `$prep->bindValue(':CYOtherExpensesAmt',$summaryData['*CYOtherExpensesAmt*'])?$row['CYOtherExpensesAmt']:''));`

I need to replace chunks of text starting with `?$row` and ending with `))`.

So example the first replacement would be:

- `$prep->bindValue(':PYOtherExpensesAmt',$summaryData['PYOtherExpensesAmt']);`

I've tried the following regexp:

`([?][$row], [))])`

Any tips on how to get this remove these blocks of text as a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regexp that will match your pattern:

```
\?\$row.*?\)\)
```

Explanation: The backslash (`\`) will escape the character in front of it so that the engine will search for literally that character. This is needed because `?`, `$`, and `)` already have special meanings in the regexp syntax. Finally, the `.*?` part means that it will match zero or more (`*`) instances of any character (`.`) in a "lazy" manner (`?`), thus stopping at the first `))`. An excellent resource for learning regex syntax: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Then, as you guessed, you should replace all matches with an empty string to remove them.